# AWS Cognito UserPool vs IdentityPool: Is IdentityPool mandatory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is using an IdentityPool mandatory with AWS Cognito?

**My use case:**

My web app has users who can self-signup and will be added to the Cognito UserPool I have set up. I only want to provide access to my backend resources to authenticated users (ie., users belonging to an authenticatedRole IAM role). My requirement is simple enough that a single authenticated role suffices to handle my application's resource authorization requirements and I just want to deny access to all backend resources for non-authenticated users.

Is this possible with just the UserPool and if yes, how do I go about accomplishing this?

Note: I am using CDK to define my Infrastructure as code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an identity pool is by no means mandatory with Cognito. It is completely on a use case basis. A few things to clarify here.

- Userpool - For authentication
- Identity Pool - For authorization

Basically, if you want your end users to sign-up, sign-in, and then access AWS resources or make AWS API calls, then you would have to use an Identity pool. So let’s say you have a gaming application where the end user can sign in via FB, Google, or natively (username and password). This is authentication, and here we would be using a Cognito user pool. Now the user is logged in and playing the game. They make a high score. This high score may need to be added to S3 or a DynamoDB table record for the user. For this, an identity pool is used. An identity pool will help you with vending temporary AWS credentials that the end user can use.

I believe in your use case the userpool should be sufficient. You can grant access to your resources by [verifying](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html) the access token returned by Cognito for the end user.